# CRA Cors Type Response

Tags: reactjs, fetch, create-react-app

I'm trying to make a POST request to a third party API, to return me a token. I've created the front with CRA.

```
 useEffect(() => {
const login = async () => {
  const bodyData = {
    username: "xxx@xxx",
    password: "xxx",
  };
  try {
    const data = await fetch(loginUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      body: bodyData,
    
    });

    const token = data;

    console.log(token);
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
 login();
 }, [])
```

The problem is that I cant receive the data,

I get this response in console:

Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://api.s360web.com/api/login', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

[image]

With POSTMAN works fine. Any recommendation?

Comment: Why exactly do you mean by "_I cant receive the data_"? You're evidently receiving a response. However, your `data` variable contains the whole `Response` object; perhaps you want to process the body of that response. Have a look at the `text` or `json` method on `Response`.

Comment: If I put data.json() I get the error Unexpected end of JSOn input...

Comment: Then that means you do not have any CORS error, but that the response body isn't valid JSON. Try `data.text()` instead.

Comment: with data.text() I get blank. @jub0bs

Comment: the body is a readable stream

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams. Anyway, your issue has got nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: yes it has. In the title I mentioned the type of the response, which is Cors...

Comment: That's not the root of your issue. If the response contained the word "banana", would you have tagged your question with "banana"?

Answer (score 0):

The status is 200 here, that means data is returned.

The body is Readable stream, it can be access by reading and then decoding

Here is the sample code to log the result

```
data.body?
 .getReader()
 .read()
 .then((val) => 
  console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(val.value))
  )
```